# How can be possible that my MacBook Pro is able to connect, automatically, to a protected wpa2 wifi network without asking any password?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, password

I have two MacBook Pro notebooks (15” mid 2010 and 13” mid 2012); I bought two new ssd disks and new ram modules for upgrading them; I installed on both Catalina (10.15.7) via usb key obviously from scratch since the disks were new. In my apartment, I have an access point, connected to Internet, with WPA2 password (a robust one) and without WPS service. After installing the os and without configuring any internet access nor configuring the wifi access (I did not put any password for that) nor any cloud account (just a local one), I noticed a very inexplicable fact: both notebooks were able to connect to the access point without inserting the password and both were able to navigate in Internet automatically. How it can be possible? Is there any hidden Apple feature that saves credentials in some chip on mainboard and they reside on it even after changing disk and installing the os from scratch? Can be it a potential security issue? Are other personal info saved in the same manner? If I want to sell my mac, how can I delete this info?

Comment: Do you have iCloud Keychain enabled on both machines, using the same Apple ID?

Comment: No, I don't have; I never created an Apple ID because I don't download anything from App Store or iTunes or whatever and I use just local account.

Comment: Your Mac can also store the WiFi password in NVRAM: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/398933/where-does-macbook-pro-store-wifi-information

Comment: @negacao That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @negacao Thanks! Now it is all clear. Bye.